# Multiple buttons in UITableViewCell in a 'top-down' UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to work out how to action buttons within a UITableViewCell when the table view is 'top down' - as in, each new row is added to the top of the table view. I achieve this with the following code:

I use the following code to insert new items into my model array and then into the tableview:

```
let newItem = Item(text: inputTextView.text, time: Date())
items.insert(newItem, at: 0) //inserting into the front of model array

tableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:0, section:0)
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Within the cellForRowAt function I run the following code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: postCellID, for: indexPath) as! NewPostCell
let item = items[indexPath.row]

cell.postTextLabel.text = text
cell.timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: time)

cell.selectionStyle = .none

return cell
```

Each of my tableview cells have three buttons in it.

How do I connect up these buttons so I know which button is pressed from which indexPath?

The problem is that if I use indexPath.row to tag the buttons, then the buttons in all cells gets tagged with 0, as each insert is happening at the top of the table at indexPath.row 0th position.

I thought of tagging the buttons with the current size of my model array, but that doesn't work either as when cells are re-used they could then be tagged with the length of the array at that point, which would be wrong.

There are a lot of apps that have 'last entry at the top' of the tableview sort of setup, with buttons in cells. So there must be a way to do this.

Comment: aside from the other answers you can use a delegate to pass the cell then convert the location of the cell to the indexPath. that way there is no need for tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `UIButton` to your `UITableViewCell` and access these `UIButton` via tag and add target method to these buttons as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableVw.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as UITableViewCell!

        //Access UIButton
        let button1:UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(10) as! UIButton
        let button2:UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(11) as! UIButton
        let button3:UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(12) as! UIButton

        //Add Action Methods to UIButtons
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FisrtButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SecondButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ThirdButtonClick), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
```

Button Actions

```
// MARK: - UIButton Methods.
    func FisrtButtonClick(_ sender: Any)  {
        //Get Button cell position.
        let ButtonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableVw)
        let indexPath = tableVw.indexPathForRow(at: ButtonPosition)
        if indexPath != nil {
            print("Cell indexPath: \(indexPath?.row)")
        }
    }

    func SecondButtonClick(_ sender: Any)  {

        //Get Button cell position.
        let ButtonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableVw)
        let indexPath = tableVw.indexPathForRow(at: ButtonPosition)
        if indexPath != nil {
            print("Cell indexPath: \(indexPath?.row)")
        }

    }

    func ThirdButtonClick(_ sender: Any)  {

        //Get Button cell position.
        let ButtonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableVw)
        let indexPath = tableVw.indexPathForRow(at: ButtonPosition)
        if indexPath != nil {
            print("Cell indexPath: \(indexPath?.row)")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was busy with something else. This looks like a good option and I will give it a go. Will also try out the method outlined by @JMM to see which works better.

Comment: Choosing this as the right answer as it appears to be the cleanest and most efficient way to solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works when we have the UIButtons count but wow can we create dynamic UIButtons (based on data model) in tableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

### Main idea

These are the basic steps you have to do:

1. **Set unique `tag` values for each of the 3 button types**: this will allow to identify which of the 3 buttons of a cell is pressed. (for instance `tag` value 1 for the first of your buttons, value 2 for the second kind, value 3 for the third button).
2. **Link the 3 buttons to a `@IBAction` method**.
   You can also do this programmatically with target-actions: call `aButton.addTarget(target:, action:, for:)` for each button.

Then when a button will be pressed, you will use an helper function to determine the cell index of the button that was pressed.

---

### Code

The `@IBAction` method should look like `@IBAction func buttonTrigerred(_ sender: UIButton){...}` and the code would be:

```
@IBAction func buttonTrigerred(_ sender: UIButton){
    // -- retrieving the index path of the cell, as @NikhleshBagdiya posted
    // Determine the indexPath of the cell
    let buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
    let cellIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    // --

    // Determine which button is called
    if sender.tag == 1 { ... }      // the first kind of button has been pressed
    else if sender.tag == 2 { ... } // second button kind
    else if sender.tag == 3 { ... } // third  button kind
}
```

#### Setting the `tag` value

> Each of my tableview cells have three buttons in it.

I suppose you have designed your UITableViewCell in a Storyboard or Xib file. So for each of the 3 buttons of your cell: select the button, go to the attributes inspector, set the `tag` to the custom values indicated above.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was busy with something else. This looks like a viable method to approach this problem but I feel like it is a bit 'hacky'. Perhaps a slightly hacky solution is needed to solve this use case. Will try it out along with what @Nikhlesh Bagdiya has suggested in the following post. Will try both out and see what works best. Thanks.